# MVC3 reloading part of page with data razor

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, reload

I have a table with my data from base and 3 buttons to delete, create and update which return PartialViews.

I want to update the part of my page with data after clicking the submit button in the corresponding dialog (delete, update, ...).

What is the easiest way to achive this?

This is what I've got now
I will just add, delete is mostly the same.

```
<div id="delete-dialog" title="Delete Product"></div>   
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(".deleteLink").button();

    var deleteLinkObj;
    // delete Link
    $('.deleteLink').click(function () {
        deleteLinkObj = $(this);
        var name = $(this).parent().parent().find('td :first').html();
        $('#delete-dialog').html('<p>Do you want delete ' + name + ' ?</p>');
        //for future use
        $('#delete-dialog').dialog('open');
        return false; // prevents the default behaviour
    });

    $('#delete-dialog').dialog({
        dialogClass: "ConfirmBox",
        autoOpen: false, width: 400, resizable: false, modal: true, //Dialog options
        buttons: {
            "Continue": function () {
                $.post(deleteLinkObj[0].href, function (data) { //Post to action
                    if (data == '<%= Boolean.TrueString %>') {
                        deleteLinkObj.closest("tr").hide('fast'); //Hide Row
                    }
                    else {
                    }
                });
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

And after dialog close I want something like a reload of a part of the page.

The data looks like

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>        Name       </th>
        <th>        Date </th>
        <th>             </th>
    </tr>


@foreach (var m in this.Model)
{
    <tr>
    <td>
     <div class="ProductName">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => m.Name)</div>
    </td>
    <td>
     @Convert.ToDateTime(m.AddDate).ToShortDateString()
    </td>
    <td>

     <div class="ProductPrice">@string.Format("{0:C}", m.Price)</div>
    </td>

    <td>
      <div class="CategoryName">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => m.CategoryName)</div>

    </td>
    <td>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = m.ID }, new { @class = "editLink" }) 
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = m.ID }, new { @class = "deleteLink" }) 
    </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

I'm not sure if im doing this well 
I tried to put this action after click the button but nut sure if is right
I changed the Index to a Partial View

```
 buttons: {
            "Continue": function () {
                $.post(deleteLinkObj[0].href, function (data) { //Post to action
                    if (data == '<%= Boolean.TrueString %>') {
                        deleteLinkObj.closest("tr").hide('fast'); //Hide Row
                    }
                    else {
                    }
                });
                $.ajax.ActionLink("Index", 
                "Index",   // <-- ActionMethod
                "Shop",  // <-- Controller Name.
                new { }, // <-- Route arguments.
                null  // <-- htmlArguments .. which are none. Y
                )
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please show what you've got so far and try to use correct spelling and punctuation, your question is hard to read.

Comment: You should look at the documentation for `Ajax.ActionLink` and `PartialView` if you want to change parts of your page.

Comment: Ok so I guess that my index should be partial view like the others and then i use actionLink thanks I think I will find the correct one for me :P

Comment: Ok I was trying to use this actionLink but not sure in good way check out last part of topic pls

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the ASP.NET MVC ActionLink helper in your .cshtml file, and not jQuery:

```
[...]
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function openPopup()
{
    // Set your options as needed.
    $("#yourPopupDialogId").dialog("open");
}
</script>
[...]
@Ajax.ActionLink( 
    "Delete", 
    "Delete", 
    "Controller", 
    new { someValue = 123 },
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        // Set your options as needed
        HttpMethod = "GET",
        UpdateTargetId = "yourPopupDialogId",
        OnSuccess = "openPopup()"
    }
)
[...]
<div id="yourPopupDialogId" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Now in your Controller for the methods you want to use for your popups you should return `PartialView`s:

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    RecordDeleteModel model = YourRepository.GetModel( id );
    return PartialView( model );
}
```